# Regular expression in FLEX finding text

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex, text-parsing

I got lex file with this rule:

```
%option noyywrap

%{
%}

LNA [^<>]
LNANA   [^<>!]

%%

(<!!)   fprintf(yyout, "begin_comment\t\t\t%s\n", yytext);
(!!>)   fprintf(yyout, "end_comment\t\t\t%s\n", yytext);
({LNANA}*|({LNA}{LNANA})*|{LNA}+{LNANA}{LNANA}{LNA})    fprintf(yyout, 
"string\t\t\t%s\n", yytext);
.   fprintf(yyout, "illegal char %s\n", yytext);
%%
```

I need to find comments between "<!!" and "!!>"  and strings in code wihout nothing

for example

```
<!! This is a comment that need to be found !!>
simple string that need to be found also
```

and this is my output:
[image]

as you can see this does not work as needed.
any help ?

Comment: Actually, I can't see that your attempt "does not work as needed" because you have only provided a very hazy description of what you want. Please provide the precise output you expect, as text (not an image). While you're editing your question, please replace the image (which is hard to read on a phone) with the actual text pasted into your question. For bonus marks, explain what you think each of your rules does.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying for.

There's certainly a regular expression which matches an entire comment (as long as you don't intend comments to nest). But it's hard to get it right, and you typically end up splitting strings and returning more tokens than necessary. Here's one which I think works, although it's not fully tested. Since you need to match the entire comment, the pattern has to include the comment delimiters. Of course, you also have to match the strings between the comments, as well as doing something in the case that a comment is not correctly terminated.

```
<!!([^!]*!)([^!]+!)*!+([^!>][^!]*!([^!]+!)*!+)*>   { /* Comment */ }
<!!    { /* This pattern will match on unterminated comments */ }
[^<]+  { /* Non comment text (but maybe not the whole string) */ }
<      { /* Also non-comment text */ }
```

A possibly clearer and probably slower version uses a start condition, and returns both the insides of comments and the rest of the text in single pieces (in `yytext`, as per the `yylex` interface).

```
%x IN_COMMENT
%%
<!!                 { BEGIN(IN_COMMENT);
                      yytext[yyleng -= 3] = 0;
                      if (yyleng) return STRING;
                    }
    /* This patterns deliberately fails if it reaches the last input */
([^<]+|<)/(.|\n)    { yymore(); }
    /* The next pattern is to catch the last character in the input */
.|\n                { return STRING; }
<IN_COMMENT>!!>     { BEGIN(INITIAL);
                      yytext[yyleng -= 3] = 0;
                      return COMMENT;
                    }
<IN_COMMENT>[^!]+|! { yymore(); }
<IN_COMMENT><<EOF>> { fputs(stderr, "Unterminated comment\n"); }
```